# Capistrano 3 How to write correctly a local task?

Tags: node.js, angular, capistrano3

In my nodjs/a,gular2 project, I am trying to run locally the build-sot process as a local task, before deploying it , but I cannot get it right , how can I set it :

```
task :build_production_aot do
  run_locally do
    set :local_app_path, Dir.pwd
    set :local_client_path, "#{fetch(:local_app_path)}/client"
    sh 'npm run build:prod-aot'
  end
end
```

thanks for feedback

UPDATE
succeeded in running the following task , but is there any better way to write it ?

```
task :build_production_aot do
  run_locally do
    local_client_path = Dir.pwd + "/client"
    puts "--> Running build: '#{local_client_path}', please wait ..."
    execute "cd #{local_client_path} && npm run build:prod-aot"
  end
end
```

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Even if it runs locally with such modified script, I guess it's better to build the production dist directly on the remote server